Idiomatic way to track if Suspense finish
Example:
  <Suspense fallback={<ClearLoading />}>
    // stuff
  </Suspense>

To track if the whole suspense node finishes loading, I put an effect cleanup in <ClearLoading> like this:
const ClearLoading = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // Do sth when suspense finish
    }
  }, []);

  return null;
};

This seems stupid. What is the generally accepted way of doing this?

To better control the loading process, you can use the useState hook in conjunction with a loading state or the useTransition as It's a little unusual to utilize a useEffect cleanup function to monitor when a suspense component has completed loading.

Using useEffect is the idiomatic approach, as mentioned in React 18 upgrade guide.
However, by moving it to an empty child component of Suspense, you wont need a wrapper for every Loading component.
<Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>
    <PullTheLever/>
    // stuff
</Suspense>

The tracking-component doesnt need a return value.
function PullTheLever() {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Do sth when suspense finish
    }, []);

    return null;
}


The problem is that I'm not sure when <PullTheLever/> is rendered. Say I have some more component below. Some are lazy loaded, some call API with use(). When will all those components be rendered? I know that they all "appear" at once, but I'm not sure if their render functions is only ran when everything is loaded. Am I just a paranoid, or my concern is valid?

React wont partially commit something to DOM, its either everything or nothing. When useEffect gets called, the entire Suspense subtree will be visible in DOM.
